# place database string value with \r\n into wpf textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox

i'm creating a small application with .edmx for database connection.

inside my database i created a string with example value:

```
this is:\r\nA new line
```

when I call this value (in debug) i see the value changed to

```
this is:\\r\\nA new line
```

resulting in a wpf textbox showing

```
this is:\r\nA new line
```

instead of

```
this is:
A new line
```

Any thoughts over what i'm doing wrong here?

EDIT:

```
Windows 8.1
VS2013 Express
SQL Server Express (LocalDb)
```

The values are stored in the database via a t-SQL command. (I'm still in the startup of the project)

```
Insert into Atable
 (ID, value)
VALUES
 (1, 'this is:\r\nA new line')
```

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: How did you enter that string into the database?  I would guess that whatever tool you used did not read the `\r\n` sequence as a carriage return + newline, but as the literal sequence "slash, r, slash, n", in which case the output is correct.  So, either store the string correctly, or manually process the escape sequences on the C# side.

Comment: windows will be reading it a char at a time from the database so when it reads it it will see \ and automatically change it to \\ so what you will need is a function to check for \\r\\n and change that to system.enviroment.newline.

Comment: how did you create this value in the database?  if you type a '\' in some tool, that probably got stored as "\\"

Comment: @RobertLevy I added the value using a T-SQL command (see edit), this for rebuilding the database at any circumstance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in sql `\r` does not mean anything special. In c#, `\r` is the same as ascii character #10, which is unprintable. What you are trying to make is an "escape sequence", which only exist in c#.

If you create the escaped character in c# and save it to sql, it will read back just fine. But if you type the escape character in sql, it won't be what you expect.

So, in an sql query, you would do this:

```sql
select 'this is:' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'A new line' -- same as "\n\r" in c#
```

In c#, it would be

```
string message = "this is\r\nAnew line"
```

Or, better, use the built in

```
string message = "this is" + Environment.NewLine + "A new line";
```

Comment: gonna try this one as soon as possible